# Sum columns in 2-D array. TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to sum all integers in each respective column, storing each sum 
in a list. When I run the code, it yields a type error = list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple.

```
array = [[3, 5, 7, 9]
        [2, 7, 3, 5],
        [1, 2, 6, 3],
        [6, 9, 5, 3]]

column_sum = []
total = 0
i = 0
for row in aList:
    total = total + row[i]
    column_sum.append(total)
    total = 0
    i = i + 1
print(column_sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is the missing comma after the first row in `array`. Additionally, you refer to `array` by `aList` in the for loop.

With those changes your code runs, but I don't think that it gives you the result you are trying to get. I think this is what you want:

```
array = [[3, 5, 7, 9],
        [2, 7, 3, 5],
        [1, 2, 6, 3],
        [6, 9, 5, 3]]

column_sum = [0, 0, 0, 0]
for row in array:
    for i, element in enumerate(row):
       column_sum[i] += element
print(column_sum)
```

Note that this way of writing it is quite low level and non-Pythonic. You should consider sing NumPy for doing these sorts of things.